# npm install puts tons of modules while I only need two, what's going on?

Tags: laravel, npm, gulp, laravel-elixir

this is my package.json

```
{
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.9.0",
    "laravel-elixir": "*"
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.0.0"
  }
}
```

I do npm install and what I get are 800 (eight hundreds) modules from "abbrev" to "yeast". What is going on??

Comment: Are they depdendencies?

Comment: I don't know. 800 modules??

Answer (score 5):

Those 3 packages you require in your **package.json** are your dependencies, but they might have dependencies of their own that also needs to be installed. Those sub-dependencies might have again some more dependencies as well - this is what results in so many packages being installed.

Have a look at dependencies of **laravel-elixir** here: https://github.com/laravel/elixir/blob/master/package.json

When you'll be deploying your package to production you can skip all devDependencies and install only what is listed in "dependencies" section by using **--production** option - this should result in less packages being installed - or even no packages with the config you pasted in your question

Comment: what I got are 800 modules, it seems a lot to me.

Comment: Why does that bother you? One of your 3 packages has 40 dependencies, each of them has again a few or a few dozens depenencies - it's easy to get even more packages installed. npm never installs a package that would not be mentioned as a dependency.

Comment: When you'll be deploying your package to production you can skip all devDependencies and install only what is listed in "dependencies" by using "--production" option